# YII2 проблема с пагинацией

Tags: php, yii2, api

Имею метод для api:

```
    public function getList(Pagination $pagination): array
    {
        $list = self::find()->with('files')->with('comments');
        $pagination->totalCount = $list->count();
        $main = $list->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->asArray()->all();
        return [
            'data'       => $main,
            'pagination' => [
                'currentPage' => $pagination->getPage(),
                'total'       => $pagination->totalCount,
                'limit'       => $pagination->getLimit(),
            ]
        ];
    }
```

проблема в том, что если у меня в get ?page=0 или ?page=1 - получаю один и тот же результат

```
    "pagination":{"currentPage":0,"total":"72","limit":20}
```

Объясните мне пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

Вы нигде не ошиблись. **get ?page=0** или **?page=1**, равно как и **get** без указания **?page** выдаст вернет вам первые 20 записей.